# Dynamic Email Signature

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, configuration

Is it possible to implement an email signature (user info, contact, website etc) in SFMC that would be attached to specific emails and would be personalised based on incoming data (Journey API entry source type for example)?

I would expect sender profile to carry such functionality but it seems not to be the case.

I am considering implementing a content block insert via AMPScirpt but still not sure if that's my only option.

Comment: I have not downvoted your question, but I can understand why it has happened. A signature in an email is nothing but Ampscript personalisation strings. Perhaps you are referring to attaching vcf file to your email instead?

Comment: Thank you - this is definitely the way go in terms of AMPScript and content... I was just not sure if there was anything OOTB/native that I am missing or SF support could add to the account configuration. I was asking about standard email signature (not vcf).

Answer (score 0):

If the dynamic rule is not complicated, you can always simply create a [Dynamic Content](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_create_dynamic_content.htm&type=5) in Content Builder.

> Use Marketing Cloud Content Builder to create dynamic content to use in email messages. Dynamic Content displays according to the rules you define based on the subscriber's attributes, data extension values, or audiences. If a subscriber meets the expression in more than one rule, the subscriber receives the content for the first rule met.

It supposes to match your need and it is easy to preview.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It's a legitimate issue, and businesses frequently inquire about an out-of-the-box solution in this area. This is a legitimate question, so those who are downvoting it should focus on providing feedback to address valid user and business concerns.